# remove scientific notation method is giving me an error

Tags: python-3.x

When I run the next line of code in pyCharm runs perfectly:

```
p = f"{price:.8f}"  # fix the scientific notation
```

But when I run it in my python 3 VPS, doesn't work. Is giving me a wrong syntaxis error. Anyone knows why?

Comment: I had problems with `f"{price:.8f}"` - try `f'{price:.8f}'` - this is empiric , according to pep498 it should make no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VPS is likely running a Python version < 3.6.  *f-strings* were introduced in Python3.6:

See [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: yep, was hard to install python 3.6.5 but worked. Thanks!